# Show all mailboxes in sidebar in neomutt?

Tags: mbox, neomutt

I am trying to set up neomutt with isync and notmuch. I have synced all mailboxes, and I can see all folders/messages in the filesystem.

However, when I start neomutt, the mailboxes are not displayed in the sidebar. I ca explicitly list mailboxes in muttrc as:

```
mailboxes +'INBOX'
```

and then they do show up in the sidebar. However, I have hundreds of folders that I use for categorizing mail, and I need to be able to quickly navigate through them, move mail around etc. And if a folder is not displayed in the sidebar, I cannot jump to it using the c shortcut.

I tried variations such as

```
mailboxes +'*'
```

or

```
mailboxes *
```

all of which just gives me errors suggesting that the * does not get expanded. I could not find any documentation on use of regexp in for mailboxes.

Does anyone know how to get all mailboxes to show up in the sidebar?

Comment: This sounds more like a configuration issue rather than a programming question.  Please note Stack Overflow is for programming questions.  Your question probably belongs to SuperUser.